# Php send Post and detect if it´s array

Tags: php, arrays, post

**Hi everybody.**

I use $_POST for send in some functions array values from select multiple, but in the function don´t detect the values are really one Array, put my example here :

```
if($_POST['send'] == "ok")
{
    function test($data_1,$data_2)
    {
        $data_one = explode(",",$data_1);
        $data_two = explode(",",$data_2);

        foreach($data_two as $two)
        {
            if (is_array($two))
            {
                print "ok";
            }    
        }
    }

    test("phone,email","".$_POST[reg][phone].",".$_POST[reg][email]."");
}
```

**Form Formulary**

```
<form id="register" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
    <br>

    <select name="reg[phone][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="reg[email]" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Register_Send" value="Register">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
    <br>

</form>
```

As you can see in the function i use is_array for detect if values are really array or no but don´t works, i want know what´s wrong for detect this, and process array inside function, thank´s for the help.

**Best Regards**

Comment: Please format your code properly, like using sensible code indention. It's very hard to follow code that has nested blocks but completely without any indention at all.

Comment: I don´t know how do this here, i put my code it´s simple and clear don´t understand you tell me

Comment: _Side note:_ When accessing an array key, the key should be quoted: `$_POST[reg][phone]` should be `$_POST['reg']['phone']`. Pre PHP 8, PHP will try and fix that for you (while throwing a warning). In PHP 8, you'll get a fatal error.

Comment: I use quotes or no the question it´s other and it´s the same put quotes or no, don´t detect if it´s array in the script that´s the question only detect if POST i send it´s array or no

Comment: I've edited the code for you. As you now can see, it's _much_ easier to see what code belongs to what block. Regarding the quotes, it was a side note/heads up, which means that it might not be the solution to this specific problem, but can cause other issues down the line.

Comment: Ok Perfect thank´s :)

Comment: There are some sever syntax issues here. What are you expecting `"".$_POST[reg][phone].",".$_POST[reg][email].""` to do? You're also not actually using `$data_one` in the function after you've defined it. To be honest, I don't really understand what the code suppose to do in the first place. It's easier if you explain what you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I send data separated by "," and in each case the post i send really it´s array because it´s multiple select, and i need detect this it´s array when send post using the function

Comment: If you only need to check if a parameter is an array, you can use [is_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php). Usage: `if (is_array($_POST['reg']['phone']))`. It if is an array, then your concatenation `"".$_POST[reg][phone]."`, you'll get a notice (or warning in php 8) about array to string conversion since you can't treat an array like a string (the concatenation).

Comment: The problem it´s the array in POST send as you can see in the function separated by "," by this use explode inside function fir get values i send inside function, and use is_array but don´t show it´s this array that´s the problem you can see this in the function

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean or what you're trying to do.

Comment: The function test send different vars separatd by ",", for explode this values inside function use explode,but some values really are arrays no single values, and need determinate these values, in the case of values as $_POST, some values are arrays dn don´t detect inside function, arrays as select multiple send by $_POST, and i want detect these values when are arrays send as $ POST